# How do you change the icon of a Gluon Desktop app?

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

How can I change the icon of a Gluon Desktop app? I changed the `icon.png` file, but that seems to only be used in the *about* dialog.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application class has a `postInit` method you can override. `Scene` is passed into it. Once you get the scene you can get the stage from it and than use normal JavaFX way to set the icon.

```
Stage stage = (Stage)(scene.getWindow());
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.png"));
```

Comment: When I try to get the stage inside of `postInit`, I'm getting stage as null. Any idea why?

Comment: That means the window is not created yet. You can attach a change listener to `scene.windowProperty` to determine when window(stage) changes